# Query for finding the tuple with other corresponding elements of value x

Tags: sql, postgresql

If we have the following table called data:
`(id, n1, n2, n3, n4)

111,  2,  4,  7, 0

444,  1,  1,  2, 1

555,  1,  1,  2, 0

777,  5,  3,  8, 0`

How do we get only (2,4,7) and (5,3,8)?

```
SELECT DISTINCT n1,n2,n3  
FROM data  
WHERE n4 = 0;
```

doesn't work as it returns the (1,1,2) tuple as well. I only need the tuples that have n4 = 0 all the time.

Comment: And also does 1,1,2 count the same as 1,2,1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options is to use [EXCEPT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-EXCEPT):

```
SELECT n1, n2, n3
FROM data
WHERE n4 = 0

EXCEPT

SELECT n1, n2, n3
FROM data
WHERE n4 <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    d.n1, d.n2, d.n3
FROM
    data d
WHERE
    d.n4 = 0
    AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
      FROM
          data d2
      WHERE
          d.id = d2.id
          AND
          --3 columns = 3 pairs. n1-n2, n1-n3, n2-n3
          (d.n1 = d2.n2 OR d.n1 = d2.n3 OR d.n1 = d2.n3))
```

Edit:

If 1,1,2 is different to 1,2,1 then

```
SELECT
    MIN(id), n1, n2, n3
FROM
    data
WHERE
    n4 = 0
GROUP BY
    n1, n2, n3
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JOIN to self:

```
SELECT d.n1, d.n2, d.n3
FROM data d
LEFT JOIN data d2 ON (d.n1 = d2.n1 AND d.n2 = d2.n2 AND d.n3 = d3.n3 AND d.n4 != d2.n4)
WHERE n4 = 0 AND d2.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

testbed:

```
create table data(id integer, n1 integer, n2 integer, n3 integer, n4 integer);

insert into data(id, n1, n2, n3, n4)
values (111, 2, 4, 7, 0), (444, 1, 1, 2, 1), 
       (555, 1, 1, 2, 0), (777, 5, 3, 8, 0);
```

assuming n4 cannot be null or negative:

```
select n1, n2, n3 from data group by n1, n2, n3 having max(n4)=0;

 n1 | n2 | n3
----+----+----
  2 |  4 |  7
  5 |  3 |  8
(2 rows)
```

if you can't assume that:

```
insert into data(id, n1, n2, n3, n4)
values (881, 1, 1, 1, -1), (882, 1, 1, 1, null), (883, 1, 1, 1, 0);

select n1, n2, n3
from data
group by n1, n2, n3
having sum(case when n4=0 then 0 else 1 end)=0;

 n1 | n2 | n3
----+----+----
  2 |  4 |  7
  5 |  3 |  8
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems fairly simple:

```
SELECT n1,
       n2,
       n3
FROM   data
GROUP  BY n1,
          n2,
          n3
HAVING Max(n4)=0 AND MIN(n4)=0;
```

That will select based only on the n1, n2, n3 tuple and where all values of n4 for the tuple groups are 0