# Beginner having difficulty with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've been studying SQL for 2 weeks now and I'm preparing for an SQL test. Anyway I'm trying to do this question:

For the table:

```
1   create table data {
2   id int,
3   n1 int not null,
4   n2 int not null,
5   n3 int not null,
6   n4 int not null,
7   primary key (id)
8   }
```

I need to return the relation with tuples (n1, n2, n3) where all the corresponding values for n4 are 0. The problem asks me to solve it WITHOUT using subqueries(nested selects/views)

It also gives me an example table and the expected output from my query:

```
01  insert into data (id, n1, n2, n3, n4)
02  values (1, 2,4,7,0),
03  (2, 2,4,7,0),
04  (3, 3,6,9,8),
05  (4, 1,1,2,1),
06  (5, 1,1,2,0),
07  (6, 1,1,2,0),
08  (7, 5,3,8,0),
09  (8, 5,3,8,0),
10  (9, 5,3,8,0);
```

expects

```
(2,4,7)
(5,3,8)
```

and not (1,1,2) since that has a 1 in n4 in one of the cases.

The best I could come up with was:

```
1   SELECT DISTINCT n1, n2, n3
2   FROM data a, data b
3   WHERE a.ID <> b.ID
4         AND a.n1 = b.n1
5         AND a.n2 = b.n2
6         AND a.n3 = b.n3
7         AND a.n4 = b.n4
8         AND a.n4 = 0
```

but I found out that also prints (1,1,2) since in the example (1,1,2,0) happens twice from IDs 5 and 6.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290050/query-for-finding-the-tuple-with-other-corresponding-elements-of-value-x  -- are you guys on  the same course?

Comment: @araqnid: lmao    @vulcanizer: I'm not a big fan of helping someone with a rating of one - especially when their first question is for hw or a test, which they should be learning on their own.  additionally, I try to avoid questions that are asking for improper use of the language or are asking for something less efficient/accurate - the proper way would be to use a subquery or join in this circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me you could try something with a grouping and having clause like

```
Select N1,N2,N3 from Data group by N1,N2,N3 having Max(N4)=0 and MIN(N4)=0
```

Comment: might also want to thrown in a `and min(N4)=0` since the table could theoretically be populated with negatives

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework...start by thinking about grouping.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use two queries and the minus operator.

Answer (score 0):

Why do Max and Min when you can just take advantage of grouping like joelt said?

```
SELECT n1,
       n2,
       n3
FROM   data
GROUP  BY n1,
          n2,
          n3
HAVING Max(n4)=0 AND Min(n4)=0;
```

Would be one option